# Check that list members are in groups of 4, in a row

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a list of objects that have coordinates. The object is something like this:

```
private class Seats
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public long PosX { get; set; }
    public long PosY { get; set; }
}
```

For all Seats inside the list, I need to know that they are in group of 4, in a horizontal row. For example, the list below is fine:

```
List<Seats> good = new List<Seats> {
    new Seats {Code = "A1", PosX = 0, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A2", PosX = 1, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A3", PosX = 2, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A4", PosX = 3, PosY = 0}
};
```

The list below is also OK (two rows):

```
List<Seats> good = new List<Seats> {
    new Seats {Code = "A1", PosX = 0, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A2", PosX = 1, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A3", PosX = 2, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A4", PosX = 3, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "B1", PosX = 0, PosY = 1},
    new Seats {Code = "B2", PosX = 1, PosY = 1},
    new Seats {Code = "B3", PosX = 2, PosY = 1},
    new Seats {Code = "B4", PosX = 3, PosY = 1}
};
```

The list below is also OK (same row, two groups, gap at (4,0)):

```
List<Seats> good = new List<Seats> {
    new Seats {Code = "A1", PosX = 0, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A2", PosX = 1, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A3", PosX = 2, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A4", PosX = 3, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A6", PosX = 5, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A7", PosX = 6, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A8", PosX = 7, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A9", PosX = 8, PosY = 0}
};
```

But the list below is not OK because there is a gap at (3,0):

```
List<Seats> bad1 = new List<Seats> {
    new Seats {Code = "A1", PosX = 0, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A2", PosX = 1, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A3", PosX = 2, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A5", PosX = 4, PosY = 0}
};
```

The list below is also not OK because there are five of them:

```
List<Seats> bad2 = new List<Seats> {
    new Seats {Code = "A1", PosX = 0, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A2", PosX = 1, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A3", PosX = 2, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A4", PosX = 3, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A5", PosX = 4, PosY = 0}
};
```

The list below is also not OK because the four Seats need to be in a horizontal row:

```
List<Seats> bad3 = new List<Seats> {
    new Seats {Code = "A1", PosX = 0, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A2", PosX = 1, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "B1", PosX = 0, PosY = 1},
    new Seats {Code = "B2", PosX = 1, PosY = 1}
};
```

For checking multiplication of 4 (it can be 8, 12, ...) I can just do:

```
list.Count % 4 == 0
```

But I need help in how to check 'in a row'.

Comment: For records to be "in one row" they should have the same PosY value.

Comment: @Ingenu I added another good sample with 2 rows.

Comment: This seems to me like a good place for someone to suggest a LINQ to objects solution; "if there is more than one member where there isn't another member with an X coordinate one lower" would be a way to express it. Also if you know the value of hte lowest X the sum of all X coords should be 4x+(1+2+3), if there are 4 and they are different and total 4x+6...    I'm curious tho if lots of people would approach this as a set-based, LINQ-is-appropriate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split all values in lists per Y value.

Then for each split list:

- Check that all Y values are equal.
- For X values: Iterate through the list, and check if the difference with the previous is equal the the previous and before previous (check if items exist).

Assuming the points are in order (as in your example), at least for X coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

The function:

```
static bool IsGood(List<Seats> seats)
{
     int size = 4;
     return seats.GroupBy(s => s.PosY)
        .Select(yGroup => new { 
            yCount = yGroup.Count(), 
            xCount = yGroup.GroupBy(x => x.PosX).Count(),
            xDistance = yGroup.Max(x => x.PosX) - yGroup.Min(x => x.PosX)
        })
        .All(g => g.yCount == size && g.xCount == size && g.xDistance == size - 1);
}
```

The tests:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", "good1", IsGood(good1) ? "good" : "bad");
Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", "good2", IsGood(good2) ? "good" : "bad");
Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", "bad1", IsGood(bad1) ? "good" : "bad");
Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", "bad2", IsGood(bad2) ? "good" : "bad");
Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", "bad3", IsGood(bad3) ? "good" : "bad");
Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", "bad4", IsGood(bad4) ? "good" : "bad");
```

Output:

```
good1 is good
good2 is good
bad1 is bad
bad2 is bad
bad3 is bad
bad4 is bad
```

The test data:

```
List<Seats> good1 = new List<Seats> 
{
    new Seats {Code = "A1", PosX = 0, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A2", PosX = 1, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A3", PosX = 2, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A4", PosX = 3, PosY = 0}
};
List<Seats> good2 = new List<Seats> {
    new Seats {Code = "A1", PosX = 0, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A2", PosX = 1, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A3", PosX = 2, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A4", PosX = 3, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "B1", PosX = 0, PosY = 1},
    new Seats {Code = "B2", PosX = 1, PosY = 1},
    new Seats {Code = "B3", PosX = 2, PosY = 1},
    new Seats {Code = "B4", PosX = 3, PosY = 1}
};
List<Seats> bad1 = new List<Seats> {
    new Seats {Code = "A1", PosX = 0, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A2", PosX = 1, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A3", PosX = 2, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A5", PosX = 4, PosY = 0}
};
List<Seats> bad2 = new List<Seats> {
    new Seats {Code = "A1", PosX = 0, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A2", PosX = 1, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A3", PosX = 2, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A4", PosX = 3, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A5", PosX = 4, PosY = 0}
};
List<Seats> bad3 = new List<Seats> {
    new Seats {Code = "A1", PosX = 0, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A2", PosX = 1, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "B1", PosX = 0, PosY = 1},
    new Seats {Code = "B2", PosX = 1, PosY = 1}
};
List<Seats> bad4 = new List<Seats> {
    new Seats {Code = "A1", PosX = 0, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "A2", PosX = 0, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "B1", PosX = 0, PosY = 0},
    new Seats {Code = "B2", PosX = 0, PosY = 0}
};
```

Comment: What about `{{PosX=0,PosY=0},{PosX=0,PosY=0},{PosX=0,PosY=0},{PosX=0,PosY=0}}`?

Comment: @AKK Great catch! Updated the answer.

Comment: But there can be gap between two groups in the same row (I added good3 in the question)

Answer (score 1):

First, check that PosY are all the same, then check that the last PosX is equal to the first PosX + the number of elements.

i.e. if the first X is 2, and there are 4 elements, then the last X must be 5.

```
public bool IsGoodSeats(List<Seats> seats, int goodNumber)
{
    if(seats.Count( seat => seat.PosY == seats[0].PosY) == goodNumber)
    {
        //var orderedSeats = seats.OrderBy(seat => seat.PosX);
        //return orderedSeats.Last().PosX == (orderedSeats.First().PosX + goodNumber - 1);
        // Actually Min and Max are better than ordering the list twice
        return seats.select(s => s.PosX).Max() == (seats.select(s => s.PosX).Min() + goodNumber - 1);
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Update** I see the question has been expanded, you are now allowed a gap after each set of 4.
Assuming the lists are ordered by Y then X, which the samples are.

```
public bool IsAllGoodSeats(List<Seat> seats, int goodNumber)
{
    if(seats.Count % goodNumber != 0)
        return false;
    for(int i = 0; i < seats.Count; i += goodNumber)
    {
        var subSeats = new List<Seat>();
        for(int s = i; s < i + goodNumber; s++)
            subSeats.Add(seats[s]);
        if(!IsGoodSeats(subSeats, goodNumber))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also because we are now assuming the seats are ordered by Y then X, IsGood Seats can become

```
public bool IsGoodSeats(List<Seats> seats, int goodNumber)
{
    if(seats.Count( seat => seat.PosY == seats[0].PosY) == goodNumber)
    {
        return seats[goodNumber - 1].PosX == (seats[0].PosX + goodNumber - 1);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't check the X values between the first and last.

Comment: Yes, it does. If the first is 0, and there are four elements, and the last element is 3, the the middle two must be 1 & 2. Oh, wait, I forgot to order the list, updating the answer now.

Comment: There can be two groups in the same row with gap in between.

Comment: @Endy: Ah, I see the the question has been expanded.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do multiple checks:

- Use `var result = seats.GroupBy(seat => seat.PosY)` and `result.All(group => group.Count == 4)` to check if there are four elements in each PosY.
- Afterwards check if there are no gaps `var noGaps = groups.All(group => SeatGapFinder.Check(group.OrderBy(seat => seat.PosX)));`
- Implement further checks as you like... ;-)

Here the code for the gap finder:

```
public static class SeatGapFinder
{
    public static bool Check(IEnumerable<Seats> seats)
    {
        using (var enumerator = seats.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                return false;
            }

            var lastValue = enumerator.Current.PosX;

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                lastValue++;

                if (enumerator.Current.PosX != lastValue)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Due to the fact that the gap finder always uses the last value it could also deal with rows that going from 7 - 11, etc. You only have to ensure that the seats are ordered (which will be done through `group.OrderBy(seat => seat.PosX)`).

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the gap finder idea

Answer (score 0):

This function should check, of a series of integers, that there are four, they are all different, and that the min is 3 less than the max - thus that there are four in a row. It doesn't require the four to be in order.

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>, bool> rowIsGood = xVals =>
    xVals.Count() == 4 &&
    xVals.Distinct().Count() == 4 &&
    xVals.Min() + 3 == xVals.Max();
```

This should group the seats by row and check that each row is good.

```
bool allRowsGood = seats.GroupBy(s => s.PosY).All(r => rowIsGood(r.Select(s => s.PosX)));
```

Comment: ... but it doesn't cover the x = {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8}, all y = 0, case.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: This seems to pass the added `good3` case too.

```
static bool CheckNGroups(IEnumerable<long> groupCont, int n = 4) {
    var lst = groupCont.ToList();
    lst.Sort();
    for(int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i+=n) {
        if (lst[i + (n - 1)] - lst[i] != n - 1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/* ... */


var bad = seatlist.GroupBy(s => s.PosY).Select((group) => group.Select(seat => seat.PosX).Distinct()).Any(xs => xs.Count() % 4 != 0 || !CheckNGroups(xs));
```